# Best way to parse screen shot of scrabble game to data structure?

Tags: computer-vision, vision

I want to parse a screenshot of an online scrabble game into a datastructure thus that I can run it through a solver to get the best move. I have no experience in computer vision, but have some basic knowledge of ML through university of courses. Any ideas would be appreciated!

I've tried google around "how to parse image of game" and related topics, I've had some experience with working with OCR libraries, but the hardest part is somehow knowing how to split the image, thus that the OCR can determine the characters.

Comment: Hi ! Do you have an example image ?

Comment: Looks like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_with_Friends#/media/File:WordsWithFriends_Screenshot.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought a bit about your problem. The main goal here is to find the horizontal and vertical interstices between all the grid cases.

Here is an image obtained by passing an horizontal gradient through the image.

[image]

Here, I remarked that the horizontal lines, between cases, that don't contain vertical edges, appear fully black. So a way to find them is to compute the mean of this image, row by row, and to take the lowest values.

Here is a graph obtained by computing this row by row mean value :

[image]

I am still working on the way to split all the rows thanks to this second image.